# Question marked as duplicate, but other question is closed

Tags: support

I'm just curious, but why would a question be marked as a duplicate if the 'duplicate' question is closed, and doesn't have an accepted answer?

The question: [How can I debug this PHP Syntax Error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768282/how-can-i-debug-this-php-syntax-error-message)

I mean, there are many comments and answers on that question, but there's no indication which one is the correct solution.

Can someone please explain this to me, I'm just curious how that works.

Comment: (Disclaimer: I know nothing about PHP) The highly voted comment on the dupe says "I wonder why PHP is complaining about a SYNTAX ERROR in an INI file. This tells me someone is trying to execute the INI file - which should not happen." so maybe edit your question to explain exactly why this is happening in your case and what you are doing to get this to happen.

Comment: @MartinSmith This is his comment, which shows that the highly voted comment does not help him.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768282/how-can-i-debug-this-php-syntax-error-message#comment43948688_27768282

Comment: Oh sorry I thought it was your question. You can also `@` notify the gold badge close voter to ask if he had a particular solution in mind when VTC-ing that question.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks, didn't know that.

Comment: A question has to be *answered* (or by the same dunce), to be a valid duplication-target. The poster accepting an answer is completely without consequence for that. I'm not qualified to judge whether either PHP question is good, or they are duplicates...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the duplicate link. The referenced answer covers the exact same topic. That the OP of the prior question never bothered to mark an answer accepted does not diminish the duplicateness. Both questions are about syntax errors, which are commonly considered off-topic either way. It might be an interesting variation of what the PHP tag endures every day, but neither question provides enough context for a technically conclusive answer.